# Delete certain content from txt file using C++

Tags: c++, file, text-files

I am seeking for help on how to delete certain content from txt file using C++. 
I know how to open a txt file and write to it, but I am not sure about how to delete certain content in a file. eg, the user opens a file, and want to write "apple" in the file, later they add "banana" in the file, and then hopes to delete "apple".

Comment: Read the file into memory, change the information in memory, overwrite the whole file with the changed contents.

Comment: There are 2 options: 1. rewrite the whole file as Richard Critten suggest. 2. use binary file and write apple with a constant width (lets say 8 characters) with space padding, than when you want to replace it, write banana with the same width as before. Note that you'll need to trim fruits with longer names,  so if width will be 8 and you want to write "strawberry" you'll write only "strawber"

Answer (score 2):

after you open the file you can keep on reading the words in it one at a time, a simple `for` loop should then search the word and remove it, you can use a char variable `word[20]` to store the user input and another char `array[]` to store the files contents. To run the loops you can use an int variable `target_length`

```
for(int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; word[j] != '\0' && j < 20 ; j++)
    {
        if(array[i] != word[j])
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            if(word[j+1] == '\0')
            {
                for(int k = (i-target_length); array[k] != '\0'; k++)
                {
                    array[k] = array[k+target_length];
                }
                i = i - (target_length+1); // move the rest of the words one place left as words are deleted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//My Assumption
//1.Comma use for seperation of string

#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
void  main () 
{

    //Writing data in file (comma use as seperator)
    std::fstream fileStream;
    std::string fileName = "TEXT.txt";
    fileStream.open (fileName, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fileStream << "APPLE"<<","<<"BANANA";
    fileStream.close();


    //Remove all "APPLE" from file
    std::ifstream readStream;
    std::string lineData;
    char * lineString;
    std::vector<char*> fileData; 

    readStream.open(fileName);
    if(readStream.is_open())
    {
        while(!readStream.eof())
        {
            std::getline (readStream,lineData);
            if(!lineData.empty())
            lineString = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(lineData.c_str()),",");
            int i= 0;
            while (lineString!=nullptr)
            {
                if(strcmp(lineString,"APPLE")!=0)
                {
                    fileData.push_back(lineString);
                    fileData.push_back(",");
                }
                lineString = std::strtok(NULL, ",");

            }
        }
    }
    readStream.close();

    //Remove the original file
    remove(fileName.c_str());


    //Created a new file with same name
    fileStream.open(fileName, std::fstream::in|std::fstream::out|std::fstream::app);
    for(int i=0;i<fileData.size();i++)
    fileStream<< fileData[i];
    fileStream.close();

    fileData.clear();


}

1) I insert data in text file using fstream.
2) I searches "APPLE" string in file.
3) I copied all content of file in vector except "APPLE" String.
4) I Remove original file.
5) I created new file with same name copied all vector data in file.
```